# How to use "maps" in anisble along with "with_items"

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, maps

I am trying to add labels to each node where a label is a map as:

```yaml
set_node_labels:
  topology.kubernetes.io/region: "syd"
  topology.kubernetes.io/zone: "syd01"
```

I have written the Ansible task as follows, however it does not work as expected:

```yaml
- name: Get all Nodes
  shell: "oc get nodes | awk '(NR>1) { print $1 }'"
  register: node_names

- name: Print phone records
  k8s:
    state: present
    kind: Node
    name: "{{ item }}"
    definition:
      metadata:
        labels: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', set_node_labels) }}"
  with_items: "{{ node_names.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: You cannot have both a `with_items` and a `loop` on the same task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you should use the existing module, when they are available instead of a `shell` module.
In your case, you can get the information about your nodes thanks to the `k8s_info` module.

So, your first taks should be:

```yaml
- name: Get all Nodes
  k8s_info:
      kind: Node
  register: node_names
```

Then in order to pass your labels, those should actually be in a dictionary, so you should be able to pass the whole `set_node_labels` as `labels`:

```yaml
- name: Print phone records
  k8s:
    state: present
    kind: Node
    name: "{{ item.metadata.name }}"
    definition:
      metadata:
        labels: "{{ set_node_labels }}"
  loop: "{{ node_names.resources }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your existing code with a little tweak

```
- name: Get all Nodes
  shell: "oc get nodes | awk '(NR>1) { print $1 }'"
  register: node_names

- name: Print phone records
  k8s:
    state: present
    kind: Node
    name: "{{ item }}"
    definition:
      metadata:
        labels: "{{ set_node_labels }}"
  with_items: "{{ node_names.stdout_lines }}"
```